# Tab press removes data in next DBEdit box in Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

In Delphi XE, when I press the tab key to exit a DBfield and go to the next DBfield, if the next field is a TDBEDit box and data is present, the data in the next TDBEDit box is removed.

How do prevent this from happening, short of writing an OnEnter procedure for the next DBEdit box?

Comment: What is a `DBField`? There's no such thing in any version of Delphi I've ever used (which is all of them since Delphi 1 except Delphi 8). I've also never encountered the behavior you describe, and I maintain more than a dozen production database (CRUD) applications on a daily basis.

Comment: Typically, when you tab to a tDbEdit, the text in that field is selected.  The whole text becomes highlighted or inverted.   If you type anything while the text is selected, whatever you type replaces the content that was there.  Is this the behavior you're describing?

Comment: looks like you have copy and paste a `TDBEdit` and paste also the event. So look at the events of that `TDBEdit` compo.

Comment: Sorry Ken, I meant to describe when tabbing to a TDBEdit box.  David, yes, when tabbing to a TDBEdit the text in that object is removed.  If I put the mouse insertion point in that box, then the text becomes highlighted and whatever I type replaces the content that was there as you describe.  But if I just tab from a previous box to a TDBEdit box, it removes what was in that box.  moskito-x, I have no events for the TDBEdit box.

Comment: It is still exhibiting the same issue.  Should I be using a different object than a TDBEdit?

Comment: Update: I have verified that I working in a table that is open, I'm in Edit mode, and I'm actively working on a new record that I've just inserted into the table.  So when I press the tab key to leave one edit box and enter another box that is a TDBEdit box, which already has data in it, the data gets removed as I enter the box.  So the data is not stored in the table yet, since I haven't issued a Post command.